# How can I make JFrame close a external window?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, jbutton

I was wondering if anyone knew how I could make JFrame close an external window. For example a .bat file. My GUI window looks like this, 
( https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/339245512647770112/372569903070183425/unknown.png )
I want to make where it says "Close" close the file that I opened with the "Run" button.

```
        btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    btnNewButton.setBounds(375, 190, 120, 40);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

    JButton btnStart = new JButton("Run");
    btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    });
    btnStart.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            try {
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Discord-Selfbot-master\\self-bot.bat"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Is it possible to make it so that I can close the file using the same or similar code? If you have any information about this then I would be happy to hear it.

Thank you for your time and consideration.
-Brand0n

Comment: Invoke windows command `tasklist` and `taskkill` in java? Using `Desktop.open()` forks another process and you can only close it by killing it via OS command.

Comment: wait so using this I could end another program / file?

Comment: Certainly, this exactly the same as you click _end process_ in _Task Manager_.

Comment: What do you mean by "Eclipse IDE GUI window"? Do you mean a `JFrame` in a program which you are writing? If so, this has nothing to do with Eclipse.

Comment: If you want full control, you should open the file and then read and display it yourself rather than handing this off to another unknown piece of software.

Comment: Yea, i'm writing the program with JFrame. I was going to make it later so that you can add any program that you want in a text bar and it would open up that program, thats why im trying to figure it out. It already opens it but you can't close the program yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the ProcessBuilder to start your program. The returned process can then be used to terminate the program.

Here is a full working code

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TestFrame {

public static void testWithoutUI(String s[]) {
    ProgramRunner programRunner = new ProgramRunner("notepad.exe");
    programRunner.start();

    System.out.println("waiting");
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    programRunner.getProcess().destroyForcibly();

    System.out.println("done");

}

public static void main(String s[]) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame Example");

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Self-Bot");


    ProgramRunner programRunner = new ProgramRunner("notepad.exe");//C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Discord-Selfbot-master\\self-bot.bat



    JButton btnStart = new JButton("Run");
    btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    });
    btnStart.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            programRunner.start();
        }
    });

    JButton buttonClose = new JButton();
    buttonClose.setText("close");

    buttonClose.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            programRunner.getProcess().destroyForcibly();
        }
    });

    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(btnStart);
    panel.add(buttonClose);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}



class ProgramRunner extends Thread{
private String pathToFile = null;
private Process process = null;

public ProgramRunner(String pathToFile) {
    this.pathToFile = pathToFile;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        startProgram();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void startProgram() throws IOException {
    process = new ProcessBuilder(pathToFile).start();
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
}

public Process getProcess() {
    return process;
  }
}
```